# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web.API change application insights instrumentation key for logging

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-2.1

I would like to enable logging to app insights from WebApi (with custom logger).
Everything works well, but I need to provide `instrumentation key` in `appsetting.json` with forced convention:

```
"Values": {
   "AppInsightsKey":  "I want to put key here" 
},
"ApplicationInsights": {
   "InstrumentationKey": "Now I must put key here"
}
```

However I can't override this second setting directly from Azure Settings:
[image]

Is there any way to set up it properly?

Actually in my `Startup.cs` I am configuring logger:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Trace);
}
```

My logger wrapper:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
...
public class MyCustomLogger : IMyCustomLogger
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyCustomLogger(ILogger<MyCustomLogger> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public void LogInformation(string message, params object[] args)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(message, args);
    }
}
```

PS. If I can override `ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey` on Azure, this will be the proper solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I can't override this second setting directly from Azure Settings:

Please add the application with following format **ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey** as appsetting key in the Azure application setting. For more information, please refer to this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjaliaga/2016/08/10/working-with-azure-app-services-application-settings-and-connection-strings-in-asp-net-core/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set instrumentation key into ENVIRONMENT Variable "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY". It should be picked up by Application Insights SDK.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Logging Component is not overriding instrumentation key by this variable from Azure. This only works, when you want to connect 'default' app insights without custom logging.

Answer (score 0):

In your Program.cs where you add Insights to the WebHostBuilder, instead of `.UseApplicationInsights()`, you can do `.UseApplicationInsights("YourKeyHere")`.

Comment: It will be problematic hence I want to keep this key in appsettings.json.